# Python throwing exception for function I didn't call

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, typeerror

I have a function with the following logic:

```py
def align(val, al): # This is technically imported from a separate file
    return (val + (al - 1)) & -al

def compileFont(font, output, audiobank_off=0):
    # Get used slot counts
    icount = font.instSlotCount()
    pcount = font.percSlotCount()
    xcount = font.sfxSlotCount()
    
    # Calculate head offset table size
    current_pos = (2 + icount) * packspecs.pointerSize()
    current_pos = align(current_pos, 16)
```

To be clear, current_pos is an integer by the last line.  When it gets to that last line, though, Python ends up throwing the following exception:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError       (note: full exception trace is
 shown but execution is paused at: <module>)
object of type 'int' has no len()
  File "tools/assemble_sound.py", line 311, in compileFont
    current_pos = align(current_pos, 16)
  File "tools/assemble_sound.py", line 1020, in main
    compileFont(font, f, aboff)
  File "tools/assemble_sound.py", line 1136, in <module> (Current frame)
    main()
```

I have no idea how len() is coming into play here.  I double-checked and the align() function doesn't even call len().  Has anyone ever seen this before?  What do I do to troubleshoot this?

Edit: I've added some more of the code and stacktrace to provide additional context. In terms of the types, current_pos is of type int.

Comment: can you please share executable code so that others can give a try

Comment: So... I tried to reduce this to a minimally-reproducible example and the error went away.  Which makes this even more confusing.  I guess I could keep reintroducing code until the error comes back, but that could make this a very lengthy example code.

Comment: maybe you can try printing the `type` of all the elements in error line

Comment: Are you pausing on exceptions with a debugger? Showing the stack trace could be very useful in finding out what is going wrong.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you could use `print()`, `print(type())` to check what you have in variables. I don't know what is `current_pos` but maybe it should have two values `(x, y)` - and maybe this can be problem because. Pair/tuple/list  `(x,y)` works with `len()`. You may not use `len()` but you may run function which run another function which uses `len()` - and full error message could show it. It doesn't have to be `align()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traceback was apparently the right clue.  For some reason, when I ran this in VS Code, the exception stacktrace it showed was incomplete (as posted above).  When I ran it from the command line, I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "oot/tools/assemble_sound.py", line 1136, in <module>
    main()
  File "oot/tools/assemble_sound.py", line 1020, in main
    compileFont(font, f, aboff)
  File "oot/tools/assemble_sound.py", line 311, in compileFont
    current_pos = align(current_pos, 16)
  File "~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/makeelf/type/align.py", line 8, in align
    full = ceil(len(b) / alignment)
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

This pointed me in the right direction that it was calling the wrong align() method.  VS Code couldn't step into align(), so I wasn't able to figure it out until I tried the command line.